# Computing the adjoint operator of Laplacian operator and applying it to the Gaussian function.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\Delta=\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x^2}}$ Laplacian operator on $\mathcal{S}:=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ Schwartz space on $\mathbb{R}.$ Then
\begin{eqnarray}
(\Delta \varphi)(x)&=&\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ix\xi}\xi^2\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)d\xi\\
&=&\mathcal{F}^{-1}(x^2\mathcal{F}(\varphi)(x))
\end{eqnarray}
for any $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}$.

Observation: $\xi^2$ is the symbol of $\Delta $

Now, the formal adjoint $\Delta^{*}$ of $\Delta$ must be holds:

\begin{eqnarray}
(\Delta\varphi,\psi)=(\varphi,\Delta^{*}\psi)
\end{eqnarray}
where $(\varphi,\psi)=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(x)\overline{\psi}(x)dx$ for any $\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{S}.$

Therefore, $$\Delta^{*}\psi(x)=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i(x-y)\xi}\xi^2\psi(y)dyd\xi$$
because

\begin{eqnarray}\displaystyle 
(\Delta\varphi,\psi)&=&\int\left( \int e^{ix\xi}\xi^2 \int e^{-i\xi y}\varphi(y)dyd\xi\right) \overline{\psi}(x)dx\\
&=&\int \left(\int \int \overline{ \overline{e^{i(x-y)\xi}} \overline{\xi^2}\psi(x)}dxd\xi\right)\varphi(y)dy\\
&=&\int \left( \overline{\int \int e^{i(y-x)\xi} \xi^2\psi(x)dxd\xi}\right)\varphi(y)dy
\\
&=&(\varphi,\Delta^{*}\psi)
\end{eqnarray}

**Question 1**. Like $\Delta\varphi(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(x^2\mathcal{F}(\varphi)(x))$. Is it possible to represent the adjoint operator in the form $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\text{some})$?

On the other hand, let $\varphi(x)=e^{-x^2}$ Gaussian function. It's known that $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}$

If i want to calculate

$$\displaystyle \int e^{ix\xi}\xi^2\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)d\xi$$   I have the advantage that  $$\displaystyle \int e^{ix\xi}\xi^2\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)d\xi=\Delta \varphi(x)=\Delta(e^{-x^2})=e^{-x^2} (-2 + 4 x^2)$$ but

**Question 2.** How compute $\Delta^{*}\varphi(x)$? with $\varphi(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

What book or text do you recommend where examples of calculations of attached operators appear?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The Laplacian is symmetric on $\mathcal{S}.$ That is, $\Delta\varphi=\Delta^*\varphi$ for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}.$ So, $\Delta^*$ is still a Fourier multiplier with the same symbol, and calculating what it does to any test function is the same as checking what $\Delta$ does to it.

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware that it was symmetrical.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you didn't show it!

Comment: $(\Delta \varphi,\psi)=\int \partial_{x^2}^{2}\varphi(x)\psi(x)dx=\int \partial_{x}\varphi \partial_{x}\psi(x)dx=\int\varphi(x)\partial_{x^2}^{2}\psi(x)dx=(\varphi, \Delta \psi) $with twice integrating by parts.

Comment: Almost! You actually have a minus sign in the middle integration by parts. Each time, you pick up a minus sign, but since you integrate by parts twice, they cancel.

Comment: Indeed! I did not put it but yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for $\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{S},$ $$\langle\Delta\varphi,\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\Delta\psi\rangle,$$ which follows directly from integrating twice by parts (the boundary terms vanish because the functions are Schwartz).

That is, $\Delta=\Delta^*$ on $\mathcal{S},$ i.e. $\Delta$ is symmetric. In particular, they have the same symbol, so they are the same Fourier multiplier. For your second question, you can calculate this simply by calculating the Laplacian of the function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do the same for the Bessel potential  $(I-\Delta)^{1/2}$ but I can't do the same (the exponent is annoying) because
$((I-\Delta)^{1/2}\varphi,\psi)=\int (1-\partial_{x^2}^2)^{1/2}\varphi(x) \psi(x)dx$ and that 1/2  is annoying

Comment: Indeed, using integration by parts isn't viable for that problem. It is more fruitful to use Fourier analysis (see my answer to your new question). Really, Fourier analysis is how we interpret the operator (Fourier multiplier functional calculus).