# What is the formal adjoint of the Bessel potential?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In a previous topic, when studying the formal adjoint of the Laplacian ([Computing the adjoint operator of Laplacian operator and applying it to the Gaussian function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140403/computing-the-adjoint-operator-of-laplacian-operator-and-applying-it-to-the-gaus)), I was able to verify that this operator is self-adjoint through the relation
$$(\Delta \varphi,\psi)=\int \partial_{x^2}^{2}\varphi(x)\psi(x)dx=\int \partial_{x}\varphi \partial_{x}\psi(x)dx=\int\varphi(x)\partial_{x^2}^{2}\psi(x)dx=(\varphi, \Delta \psi)$$

But, doing the same with the Bessel potential $(I-\Delta)^{1/2}$ the exponent is annoying and I can't replicate the same argument. In this case, should the attachment be found differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use Fourier analysis here, since the definition of the operator is through the Fourier multiplier functional calculus. Call $A=(I-\Delta)^{1/2}.$ Recall that it is a Fourier multiplier with symbol $\langle \xi\rangle,$ i.e. $\widehat{A\varphi}(\xi)=\langle\xi\rangle\hat{\varphi}(\xi),$ where $\langle\xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}.$ Then, by Plancherel's theorem,

\begin{align*}
(A\varphi,\psi)&=(\widehat{A\varphi},\hat{\psi})=\int \langle\xi\rangle\hat{\varphi}\overline{\hat{\psi}}\, d\xi=\int \hat{\varphi}\overline{(\langle\xi\rangle\hat{\psi})}\, d\xi=(\hat{\varphi},\widehat{A\psi})=(\varphi, A\psi).
\end{align*}

So, it is symmetric on $\mathcal{S}.$ Through this process, one can observe that any Fourier multiplier with real symbol is symmetric on $\mathcal{S}.$